# Capistrano invoke deploy multiple times?

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3

We're working on a system that allows us to deploy multiple projects at once with capistrano. We have 3 systems in place (front, billing, app) that all have a separate codebase and are deployed on different servers in multiple stages.

Using the capistrano_multiconfig to create one capistrano repo with multiple configurations works like a charm. I can run each command separately and they all deploy fine to the right server in the right stage.

Now I would like to add a custom task that deploys all the configured projects at once with a single command. I've pasted the command code below.

```
set :projects, ['front', 'billing', 'app']

namespace :deploy do
    desc 'Deploy all'
    task :all do 
        set :env, ask('To what environment do you want to deploy?', 'staging');
        run_locally do
            fetch(:projects).each { |project| 
                info "Now deploying #{project} to #{fetch(:env)}" 
                invoke "#{project}:#{fetch(:env)}"
                invoke "deploy"
            }
        end
    end
end
```

The issue is that the code above only deploys the first project, the info command executes for all iterations of the `.each` loop but the invocation of the deploy command only runs for the first project, after that the following two invoke calls just do nothing.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Are all of the 3 apps deployed as a single body? If not, the user might see some errors as one part is up and is incompatible with the rest. Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 3):

you should reenbale the task

Rake::Task["deploy"].reenable